# if year equals current year then calendar month to current month in cognos report studio

Tags: cognos

I have created a report with a slider that filters on year.  The client however would like to not see the future month zero values. I am not quite sure how to modify the year and month filters so that if [fiscal year] = (year(current_date) then [Fiscal Year Month Number] to (month(current_date)  I have attached a couple of screenshots.  "Period" in the X axis is sorted by Fiscal Year and Fiscal Year Month Number.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9tXL.png)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add this as a filter when I should have added it as a new measure.
if([Fiscal Year]=[Current Year] and [Fiscal Year Month #]<=[Current Month]) then ([Corp FY Data])
else
if([Fiscal Year]=[Current Year] and [Fiscal Year Month #]>[Current Month]) then (null)
else
if([Fiscal Year]>[Current Year]) then (null)
else
if([Fiscal Year]<[Current Year]) then ([Corp FY Data]) else (0)

Problem resolved. Yeah me. ;)